# Skipping first line in pipes-attoparsec

Tags: haskell, attoparsec, haskell-pipes

My types:

```
data Test = Test {
 a :: Int,
 b :: Int
} deriving (Show)
```

My parser:

```
testParser :: Parser Test
testParser = do
  a <- decimal
  tab
  b <- decimal
  return $ Test a b

tab = char '\t'
```

Now in order to skip the first line, I do something like this:

```
import qualified System.IO as IO    

parser :: Parser Test
parser = manyTill anyChar endOfLine *> testParser

main = IO.withFile testFile IO.ReadMode $ \testHandle -> runEffect $
         for (parsed (parser <* endOfLine) (fromHandle testHandle)) (lift . print)
```

But the above `parser` function makes every alternate link skip (which is obvious). How to only skip the first line in such a way that it works with Pipes ecosystem (`Producer` should produce a single `Test` value.) This is one obvious solution which I don't want (the below code will only work if I modify testParser to read newlines) because it returns the entire `[Test]` instead of a single value:

```
tests :: Parser [Test]
tests = manyTill anyChar endOfLine *>
        many1 testParser
```

Any ideas to tackle this problem ?

Comment: By the way, you switch between `Test` and `Link`.

Comment: @Zeta Sorry, that's my mistake. Updated to make it `Test`. (My original data structure is actually `Link` which has more fields. I just simplified it to `Test` for this question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can drop the first line efficiently in constant space like this:

```
import Lens.Family (over)
import Pipes.Group (drops)
import Pipes.ByteString (lines)
import Prelude hiding (lines)

dropLine :: Monad m => Producer ByteString m r -> Producer ByteString m r
dropLine = over lines (drops 1)
```

You can apply `dropLine` to your `Producer` before you parse the `Producer`, like this:

```
main = IO.withFile testFile IO.ReadMode $ \testHandle -> runEffect $
    let p = dropLine (fromHandle testHandle)
    for (parsed (parser <* endOfLine) p) (lift . print)
```

Comment: What is don't want to drop a line, but just await lines? Is there a way better than `over lines (drops o)`?

Comment: @Igor With the exception of `Pipes.Prelude`, the `pipes` ecosystem discourages reading entire lines into memory since they could be arbitrarily long.  To see how to do this idiomatically, study the [Pipes.Group tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-group-1.0.1/docs/Pipes-Group-Tutorial.html) and check out [Pipes.Text.lines](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-text-0.0.0.15/docs/Pipes-Text.html#v:lines)

Answer (score 5):

If the first line doesn't contain any valid `Test`, you can use `Either () Test` in order to handle it:

```
parserEither :: Parser (Either () Test)
parserEither = Right <$> testParser <* endOfLine 
           <|> Left <$> (manyTill anyChar endOfLine *> pure ())
```

After this you can use the functions provided by `Pipes.Prelude` to get rid of the first result (and additionally of all non-parseable lines):

```
producer p = parsed parserEither p 
         >-> P.drop 1 
         >-> P.filter (either (const False) (const True))
         >-> P.map    (\(Right x) -> x)

main = IO.withFile testFile IO.ReadMode $ \testHandle -> runEffect $
         for (producer (fromHandle testHandle)) (lift . print)
```